# Probability of a different electoral system returning a different result

Tags: probability, voting-theory

Consider an election with three candidates: A, B and C. Each voter orders the candidates randomly (ABC, ACB, BAC, BCA, CAB or CBA), such that there is a 1/6th chance of voting for each of the options. What is the probability that the party which received the most first preference votes (and hence would have won in a 'first past the post' electoral system) does not win in a preferential electoral system?

---

Background:
In the UK, US, India and many other nations, a 'first past the post' electoral system is used: that is, each voter ticks their preferred candidate, and the candidate with the most votes wins. In elections with more than one candidate, the winning candidate may receive less than 50% of the vote.

In many other nations (including my native Australia), an 'instant runoff' or  preferential voting system is used: each voter numbers the candidates in a list of their preference. After the election, the candidates are ordered according to who received the most first preference votes. The least popular party is eliminated, and its votes are redistributed according to the preferences of those who voted for the party. This process is repeated until there are only two parties left, by which stage one will have more than 50% of the vote.

---

My 'brute force' computer model returns the answer that, around 24% of the time, the different electoral systems return a different result.  Any ideas for an analytical solution/proof?

Comment: You may like to read https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arrow%27s_impossibility_theorem, but it won't help with this question.

Comment: Which voting system do you mean by _preferential electoral system_? 
(_preferential electoral system_ is a whole family of voting rules)

Comment: @Snochacz This seems to be described in the last paragraph.  Is there some reason the description is inadequate?  It doesn’t prescribe the outcome of a tie, but I would guess this becomes less relevant as the population increases and one should be able to find a precise limiting probability.

Comment: @Snochacz. What I mean by this system can best be illustrated by an example. Suppose, in an electorate of 9000 voters, 4000 vote for candidate A, 3000 vote for candidate B, and 2000 for candidate C. C is eliminated, and those 2000 votes 'flow' to each of their 2nd preferences. In this case, suppose 80% of those who voted 'C' first had 'B' second, and the other 20% had A 'second'. The final, two party preferred vote, is 4400 for A (4000 primary + 400 in preferences) vs 4600 for B (3000 primary + 1600 in preferences). This is an example of preferential voting having a result different from FPP.

Comment: You should probably say "[Instant-runoff voting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Instant-runoff_voting)" to differentiate from the dozens of other preferential systems.